# How can i consume twitter api which returns result as json in ASP.Net using c# (Web Form)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, twitter

I have am using default twitter profile widget to show the tweets of the users.

```
https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile
```

Unfortunately it doesn't show the number of followers so i got hold of a api that send all the necessary details as json. below is the URL for the same.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true
```

I want to use the "followers_count" and display it on the profile widget.

I would appreciate if someone point me to an example which consumes such JSON result in asp.net using c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer [Json.Ne](http://json.codeplex.com/)t to parse json

```
WebClient cln = new WebClient();
string json = cln.DownloadString("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true");
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",obj.location,obj.screen_name,obj.followers_count);
```

Comment: @LB: For this i need to install JSon framework. I cant find any DLL for the same so that i can add it to my bin folder and start using it. Is their any other way of adding json.net reference to project rather than installing nuGet package then then install json.net using this...

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker You can download the zip file (including source+binaries) from main page. Just reference the dll from your project. that is all